# use textbox to search multiple view functions in django

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views

Hello I am very new to Django/python - I have a scenario where I am seeking some directional guidance/advice , so I have a basic template with a searchbox `vaule = rep_date`

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
  </head>
  <body>

      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-2">
          <h1 style="text-align:center;position:relative">MENU</h1>

            <nav class="navbar bg-ligh">
                <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="">
                {% csrf_token %}
                   <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-sm" value="rep_date">
                   <input type="submit" value="ok">
                </form>
                <ul class="navbar-nav">
                    <li class="nav-items"><a href="" class="nav-link">Report 1</a></li>
                    <li class="nav-items"><a href="#" class="nav-link">Report 2</a></li>
                    <li class="nav-items"><a href="#" class="nav-link">Report 3</a></li>
                    <li class="nav-items"><a href="#" class="nav-link">Report 4</a></li>
                    <li class="nav-items"><a href="#" class="nav-link">Report 5</a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
          {% block content %}

          {% endblock %}
        </div>
      </div>

  </body>
</html>
```

after the submission of the textbox i am trying to return the respective views for each report from the side nav bar, using the input value from the posted textbox to feed into the view for the final view results to render each html page

sample for the view for each report:

```
def ReportOne(request):
    RepOneResult = Reporttable.objects.filter(yyyy_mm=PostedVal).order_by("-approved")[:25]
    return render(request, "reports/RepOne.html", {'RepOneResult': RepOneResult})
```

So I am having issues appling the code logic along with including the form posted `value = rep_val` in each view

Answer (score 0):

A couple of ways I can think you can do this,

1- you can create a URL pattern for each view and according to the clicked report you pass to the corresponding view. It would look something like this,

```
<form id="reportForm" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="">
     {% csrf_token %}
     <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-sm" value="rep_date">
     <input type="submit" value="ok">
</form>

<a class='report-link' href='#' data-action='{% url "report_one" %}'>Report 1</a>
<a class='report-link' href='#' data-action='{% url "report_two" %}'>Report 2</a>
<a class='report-link' href='#' data-action='{% url "report_three" %}'>Report 3</a>
```

and some js/jquery

```
$('.report-link').click(fucntion() {
    $('#reportForm').attr('action', $(this).attr('data-action'))
    $('#reportForm').submit()
})
```

2- You can also achieve that by having a single view for your reports as so,

```
<form id="reportForm" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="">
     {% csrf_token %}
     <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-sm" value="rep_date">
     <input type="submit" value="ok">
</form>
<a class='report-link' href='#' data-action='{% url "reports" %}?report=report_one'>Report 1</a>
<a class='report-link' href='#' data-action='{% url "reports" %}?report=report_two'>Report 2</a>
<a class='report-link' href='#' data-action='{% url "reports" %}?report=report_three'>Report 3</a>
```

then in your reports view, you can just check the GET parameter and generate the report accordingly like so,

```
def reports(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if 'report' in request.GET and request.GET['report'] == 'report_one'
            generate_report_1()
        elif 'report' in request.GET and request.GET['report'] == 'report_two'
            generate_report_2()
        elif 'report' in request.GET and request.GET['report'] == 'report_three'
            generate_report_3()
        # ... and so on
```

I prefer the second method for the reason that I wouldn't need to add a URL pattern for each report I create and that makes things a little more dynamic.

Hope this helps!